# Setting Up the Entity Framework Provider for Intersystems Cache 2018

Tags: entity-framework, intersystems-cache

I am trying to setup Entity Framework for Cache in Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition running on Windows Server 2022.

I am following the guide at https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GBMP_eframe#GBMP_efinstall.

1. **devenv /setup**  - no issues
2. **setup.cmd** - fails "*Installer.exe: #053 @ 2022.09.19T12:09:15.0917142: TraceOps.ShowMessage: could not open registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx*

I created the Registry folder *AssemblyFoldersEx*, reran **setup.cmd** and it ran sucessfully.

3. I did not have the path defined in the installation notes so I created it **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen** and copied the files (3 in total) as instructed.

I open VS 2022 and Try to select the data source.  Cache is not showning.

---

Can someone please guide me on what I am missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using older Visual Studio. Cachè 2018 was released before Visual Studio 2022, so the extension might not work there